# Unix quota per user script

Tags: unix, shell-scripting, quota

Is there any way to automate user's home folder qouta by script. I have auto `useradd` script, and I want to add code in script about quota for home folder of size 2 GB. For example:

```
edquota sally

    Disk quotas for user sally (uid 1045):
  Filesystem                   blocks       soft       hard     inodes     soft     hard

  /dev/loop0                       16       0           0          4        0        0
```

How to make command `edqouta` change value of hard limit from 0 to 2037760 by script? in other words how to modify `edquota sally` to automatically change value.

Answer (score 2):

`edquota` is not really suitable for scripting.

[quotatool](https://github.com/ekenberg/quotatool) handles quotas from the commandline. Easy to use in scripts. It's included in most major Linux distributions, and is also available for *BSD, Mac OSX, AIX and Solaris.

Comment: Looks like quotatool does not work with user-ids that do not exist, right?

Comment: Oh, it does. You have to prepend : (colon) before the user ID

Answer (score 1):

OK, it looks like you did man edquota :-)

It looks like all you need to do is append some text into the quota files:
i.e.

```
echo 'text' >> /quota.user
```

For example in OpenBSD, you would use:

```
FILES
 quota.user   at the filesystem root with user quotas
 quota.group  at the filesystem root with group quotas
 /etc/fstab   to find filesystem names and locations
```